# SQL update selected rows with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update selected rows in t1 using data in t2. I *think* the UPDATE / INNER JOIN is fine, but I'm not sure how to limit the rows updated to those in the SELECT in a combined statement:

```
SELECT * FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE channel_id = 12

UPDATE exp_channel_data t1
 INNER JOIN exp_channel_titles t2 ON t1.entry_id = t2.entry_id
 SET t1.field_id_131 = t2.url_title
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data t1
 INNER JOIN exp_channel_titles t2 ON t1.entry_id = t2.entry_id AND t2.channel_id = 12
 SET t1.field_id_131 = t2.url_title
```